# Inserting typedef map into a hash table

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, hashtable, unordered-map

In the program below I've a `typedef map`. What I want to do is to implement a hash table. I'm trying to use `unordered_map` since I heard that is the efficient as it takes O(1) time. I use my `typedef map` everywhere in my main program (another program that I'm working on) so I don't want to change that. I want to implement hash table in one of the functions and I'm trying to figure out how to insert the contents of my map into the hash table and search for the key later. I've inserted a comment in two places where I'm having trouble. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> v_t;
typedef set<int> s_t;
typedef map<s_t, v_t> m_t;
typedef m_t::iterator m_it;
typedef std::unordered_map<s_t, v_t> Mymap;

int main(){
    m_t sample;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i+2) {
        v_t v;
        for(int k = 100 ; k<=105 ; ++k)
            v.push_back(k);
        s_t k;
        k.insert(i);
        sample.insert(sample.end(), make_pair(k, v));
    }

    //---------Debug--------------------
    for( m_it it(sample.begin()) ; it!=sample.end(); ++it) {
        cout << "Key: ";
        copy(it->first.begin(), it->first.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        cout << " => Value: ";
        copy (it->second.begin(),it->second.end(),ostream_iterator<double>(cout," "));
        cout << endl;
    }
    //---------------------------------

    Mymap c1;

    for( m_it it(sample.begin()) ; it!=sample.end(); ++it) {
        c1.insert(Mymap::value_type(it->first,it->second));   // how to do this ?
    }
    s_t s;
    s.insert(72);
    if(c1.find(s)!=c1.end())                                // does this work ?
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help or comments.

After reading Jason's comments I understand why i cannot use a `std::set` as a key in `unordered_map` so I tried to use `std::string` as a key but the `find` function won't work. Could you please help me.

```
Mymap c1;

for( m_it it(sample.begin()) ; it!=sample.end(); ++it) {
    v_t v1;
    std::string key;
    key.insert(key.begin(),it->first.begin(),it->first.end()); 
    copy(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(),std::back_inserter(v1));
    c1.insert(Mymap::value_type(std::make_pair(key,v1)));
}

string s = "72";
if((c1.find(s) != c1.end()) == true) 
    cout << "Success" << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: Make sure you're compiling with C++0x support ... that may require you to set the proper flag with gcc, such as `gcc -std=c++0x` or `gcc -std=gnu++0x` ... you'll also need to re-define you key-values, as you can't directly convert an `int` to a `string` without using a helper function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic element you're missing to make this work is to define a hashing function for your `std::set` that you're using as the key.  The STL already defines equality and lexicographical ordering for a `std::set`, so you can use it as the key-value in a `std::map` as-is without any problems.  It does not define a hash function though, so that is something you're going to have to-do by overloading std::hash.  This is fairly straight-forward, and can be done by defining the following function:

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<std::set<int> > : public std::unary_function<std::set<int>, size_t>
    {
        size_t operator()(const std::set<int>& my_set) const
        {
           //insert hash algorithm that returns integral type
        }
    };
}
```

The above functor object would return an integral type of `size_t`, and would take a `std::set` as the argument.  You'll have to define it inside of `namespace std` so that `std::unordered_map` will recognize it.  An "easy" algorithm could be simply summing the elements since you have a set of type `int`.  There are more complex algorithms out there that would reduce the number of collisions such a simple algorithm would create at the expense of hashing time.  Once you have this defined though, you shouldn't have any problems inserting your `std::set` key-values into an `unordered_map`, as well as creating new key-values and finding them in the hash table.

You can see an example of your source-code working at: http://ideone.com/DZ5jm

EDIT: Jason's [code](http://ideone.com/DZ5jm) placed here for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

namespace std
{
        template<>
        struct hash<set<int> > : public unary_function<set<int>, size_t>
        {
            size_t operator()(const std::set<int>& my_set) const
            {
               set<int>::iterator iter = my_set.begin();
               int total = 0;

               for (; iter != my_set.end(); iter++)
               {
                   total += *iter;
               }

               return total;
            }
        };
}



typedef vector<int> v_t;
typedef set<int> s_t;
typedef map<s_t, v_t> m_t;
typedef m_t::iterator m_it;
typedef std::unordered_map<s_t, v_t> Mymap;

int main(){

m_t sample;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i+2) {
        v_t v;
        for(int k = 100 ; k<=105 ; ++k)
           v.push_back(k);
        s_t k;
        k.insert(i);
        sample.insert(sample.end(), make_pair(k, v));
    }

//---------Debug--------------------
for( m_it it(sample.begin()) ; it!=sample.end(); ++it) {
   cout << "Key: ";
   copy(it->first.begin(), it->first.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
   cout << " => Value: ";
   copy (it->second.begin(),it->second.end(),ostream_iterator<double>(cout," "));
   cout << endl;
   }
//---------------------------------

Mymap c1;

for( m_it it(sample.begin()) ; it!=sample.end(); ++it) {
   c1.insert(Mymap::value_type(it->first,it->second));   // how to do this ?
   }
s_t s;
s.insert(72);
if(c1.find(s)!=c1.end())                                // does this work ?
   cout << "Success" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess I made a mistake by telling it is ordered. It is not and I'll edit it. But I could still use `sample.find(s);` to find a value in the `map` where `s` is a `std::set` as defined in the program. Can i do the same with `unordered_map` ?

Comment: Just as a note: You **can** define a strict (weak) ordering on a set of strictly (weakly) ordered elements: `set1 < set2` if `*set1.begin() < *set2.begin()`. If the first (i.e. smallest) elements are equal you can iterate. If all elements are equal the containers are equal if they are of equal length, otherwise the container with the least elements is smaller. This is the canonical ordering that you would apply to numbers (from right to left, though).

Comment: You can do the same, but again, if you stored the key-values as *pointers* to your sets, you are not going to have to worry about the above rules of equality for your key-values ... the fact that the pointers to two different sets are not going to be equal (can't be equal), gives you a nice way to differentiate sets.  Furthermore pointers are easy to hash, and easy to sort, so they make great key-values for both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.  For protection against memory leaks you can store them inside a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @bitmask ... yes, very true ... the same can be done for lexigraphically ordering a string.  I wasn't trying to say it can't be done, but that it's just cumbersome ... any quick technique won't work.  Defining a lexigraphical order can be a time-consuming process, and using pointers can circumvent this issue altogether.

Comment: It would be helpful for me to understand better if you could give an example or edit my code. I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to say. Sorry if I'm wrong but I do not worry about the order or anything here. I just want to associate a `std::map` with a `std::vector` in a hash table. If I'm able to do the same perfectly with `std::map` why can't I do it with `unordered_map` ?

Comment: Sorry Sunil ... after trying to convert your code over to what I was talking about, I see I've made my answer needlessly complex ... I'm going to be changing it quite a bit ...

Comment: @Jason: Thank you very much. I understand what you're saying and I've edited my question with a few concerns. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @jason: Also could you please give a very simple hash algorithm inside ? Because I'm new to C++ and I do not understand templates that much. I can call the function like `hash(s1);` where `s1` is a `set` of numbers say 4,5,7. So how should I write the algorithm inside ? Thanks

Comment: @Sunil I've created a working copy with a simple summation algorithm, and put a link to a compiled and working copy in my answer.  You can also check it out here: http://ideone.com/DZ5jm